# How to draw Root locus for two gains

Tags: polynomials, control-theory

In the book I'm reading, one of the exercises asks to draw the root locus for this ***closed-loop***  system
$$
\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)} = \frac{1}{s^2 + K_2 s + K_1}
$$

I never encounter such a problem for two gains. I usually do it for a single gain where I can change the gain and observe how the poles of the closed-loop system move in the s-plane. Any suggestions for handling this?

Comment: It isn't a problem for two gains. Just draw your locus diagram using $s=j\omega$ and calculate the value of $\Re(H(\omega))$ and  $\Im(H(\omega))$  . So $\omega$ is your parameter for the curve and just indicate the specific point you mention depending on $K1$ and $K2$ (calculate discriminant) . **The key is to draw W depending  on $\Re(H(\omega))$ and  $\Im(H(\omega))$which will be easy as you have the expressions of $\Re(H(\omega))$ and  $\Im(H(\omega))$ Where $\Re(H(\omega))$ and  $\Im(H(\omega))$** denotes real and imaginary part of $H$

Comment: But what is more simple is simply to calculate the gain and the phase of $H$ at $\omega=0$ and $\omega= \infty$ and calculate them beteween in order to complete the diagram more easliy

Comment: @EDX could you please elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Because we want to calculate our transfer function in the complex plane modulus and phases are sufficient to trace it.

Let $$H : s \to \dfrac{1}{s^2+K_1s+K_2}$$

Setting $s=j \omega$

$$ H(jw)=\dfrac{1}{(K_2-\omega^2)+j\omega K_1}$$
which is by multiplying by conjugate quantity

$$ H(jw)=\dfrac{(K_2-\omega^2)-j\omega K_1}{(K_2-\omega^2)^2+(\omega K_1)^2}$$

**Now for gain:**

$$ |H(j\omega)|=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(K_2-\omega^2)^2+(\omega K_1)^2}}\\H(0)=1 \\ |H(j\omega)_{\omega \to \infty}|=0$$

**Now for phase:**

$$ Arg(H(j\omega))= \arctan\left(\dfrac{-\omega K_1}{K_2-\omega^2}\right) +\mathbb{1}_{\omega \geq \sqrt{K2}}(\omega)\pi$$

So here to **gain many time** it is fundamental to take time to study the phase of $H$.

Variations are as follow (phases must be continous)

$$ \text{On} \ [0,\sqrt{K2}] \ , \text{decreasing}\\
    \text{At} \ \sqrt{K_2} \  \text{we get a phase of} \ -\pi/2 \mod \pi\\\text{Then decreasing to } -\pi \mod \pi $$

So you will get this form :

[image]

The modulus at intersection with imaginary axis will be $\frac{1}{K_1\sqrt{K_2}}$.

So the diagramm consists in **fixing $K_1$** and trace your diagramm in function and making it for different value of $K_1$ as it is made on the picture ( don't take in account the letter $z$)

Comment: This is not root locus diagram.